# Delta function and $\sum_{t}\exp\{ i k t\} $

Tags: fourier-transform, exponential-sum

I am interested in evaluating the following, which appears in an integrand,
$$
\sum_{t=0}^{\infty}e^{ikt}
$$
where $k$ is real. Using the following relation
$$
\sum_{t=-\infty}^{\infty}e^{ikt} = 2\pi\delta(k),
$$
the real part of it is

\begin{eqnarray}
\Re\left[\sum_{t=0}^{\infty}e^{ikt}\right]&=&\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\Re\left[\sum_{t=-\infty}^{\infty}e^{ik}\right]\\&=&\frac{1}{2}+\pi\delta(k).
\end{eqnarray}

Note the addition of $\frac{1}{2}$ term! This $\frac{1}{2}$ term does not agree with the following derivation using $\epsilon$ trick!

\begin{eqnarray}
\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0_{+}}\lim_{T\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{t=0}^{T}e^{ikt}e^{-\epsilon t}&=&\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0_{+}}\lim_{T\rightarrow\infty}\frac{e^{\epsilon}-e^{ik\left(T+1\right)}e^{-\epsilon T}}{e^{\epsilon}-e^{ik}}\\
&=&\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0_{+}}\frac{1}{e^{\epsilon}-e^{ik}}
\end{eqnarray}

which becomes, when $k \rightarrow 0$,

\begin{eqnarray}
\lim_{k\rightarrow0,}\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0_{+}}\frac{1}{e^{\epsilon}-e^{ik}}&=&\lim_{k\rightarrow0,}\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0_{+}}\frac{1}{\epsilon-ik}\\
&=&\lim_{k\rightarrow0}\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0_{+}}\frac{i}{k+i\epsilon}\\&=&\lim_{k\rightarrow0}\left[\pi\delta\left(k\right)+i\mathcal{P}\frac{1}{k}\right]
\end{eqnarray}

where [Sokhotsky's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sokhotski%E2%80%93Plemelj_theorem) is used.

Now when $k\nrightarrow0$,
$$
\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0_{+}}\frac{1}{e^{\epsilon}-e^{ik}}=\frac{1}{1-e^{ik}}
$$

Therefore, for all $k$,
$$
\sum_{t=0}^{\infty}e^{ikt}=\pi\delta\left(k\right)+\mathcal{P}\frac{1}{1-e^{ik}}
$$

Note that the real part of it does not have $\frac{1}{2}$ addition term, instead has $\Re\mathcal{P}\frac{1}{1-e^{ik}}$.

What am I doing wrong?

---

Building on Svyatoslav's answer which in turn supported by vitamin d, the conclusion is the following:
$$
\sum_{t=0}^{\infty}e^{ikt} = \frac{1}{2} + \pi \delta(k) + \frac{i}{2} \mathcal{P} \cot (k/2)
$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: The Cauchy Principal Value only makes sense when applied to an integral. $\mathcal{P}\frac1k$ and $\mathcal{P}\frac1{1-e^{ik}}$ make no sense.

Comment: @robjohn Oh, the summation actually is a factor of an integrand. I will modify the question. Thanks

Comment: @KileanHwang I made an edit. I proved that the $\varepsilon$-regularization Svyatoslav made is indeed a nascent delta function.

Comment: The sum has to be a periodic distribution. $\sum_{t \geq 1} e^{i t k}/t$ is the same in the pointwise and in the distributional sense (because we can take the summand of the pointwise sum to be zero at $k \in 2 \pi \mathbb Z$ and bound the partial sums by an integrable function), so
$$\sum_{t \geq 0} e^{i t k} =
(k + i \ln(1 - e^{i k}))' =
\mathcal P {\left( \frac 1 {1 - e^{i k}} \right)} +
 \pi \sum_{t \in \mathbb Z} \delta(k - 2 \pi t).$$
$\mathcal P(1/(1 - e^{i k}))$ and $i \mathcal P(\cot(k/2))/2 + 1/2$ are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we do formal calculations (without the proof of validity) we get

$S(k)=\sum_{t=0}^{\infty}e^{ikt}=1+\sum_{t=1}^{\infty}e^{ikt}+\sum_{t=-1}^{-\infty}e^{ikt}-\sum_{t=-1}^{-\infty}e^{ikt}=\sum_{t=-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{ikt}+1-\sum_{t=0}^{\infty}e^{-ikt}$

$\Rightarrow$ $S(k)+S^*(k)=1+2\pi\delta(k)$

On the other hand, if we use $\epsilon$-regularization

$$S(k,\epsilon)=\sum_{t=0}^{\infty}e^{ikt-\epsilon{t}}=\frac{e^{\epsilon}}{e^{\epsilon}-e^{ik}}=\frac{e^{\epsilon}(e^{\epsilon}-e^{-ik})}{1+e^{2\epsilon}-e^{\epsilon}(e^{ik}+e^{-ik})}=\frac{e^{\epsilon}-\cos{k}+i\sin{k}}{e^{\epsilon}+e^{-\epsilon}-(e^{ik}+e^{-ik})}$$

$$S(k,\epsilon)=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sinh\epsilon+i\sin{k}}{2(\cosh\epsilon-\cos{k})}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sinh\epsilon}{2(\cosh\epsilon-\cos{k})}+\frac{i\sin{k}}{2(\cosh\epsilon-\cos{k})}$$

$S(k,\epsilon)\to\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{\epsilon^2+k^2}=\frac{1}{2}+\pi\delta(k)$,  $k<<\epsilon$, $\epsilon\to0$

$S(k,\epsilon)\to\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\frac{\sin{k}}{1-\cos{k}}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\cot\frac{k}{2}$, $k>>\epsilon$, $\epsilon\to0$

$S(k,\epsilon)+S^*(k,\epsilon)\to1+2\pi\delta(k)$ for all $k$

Comment: Thanks. It is very clear including the imaginary part. I will add them to the question.

Comment: Oh, it seems that there is a sign error on
$\sum_{t=0}^{\infty}e^{ikt-\epsilon{t}}=\frac{e^{\epsilon}}{e^{\epsilon}-e^{ik}}$
Can you recheck it? Thanks

Comment: $\sum_{t=0}^{\infty}e^{ikt-\epsilon{t}}=\frac{1}{1-e^{-\epsilon}e^{ik}}=\frac{e^{\epsilon}}{e^{\epsilon}-e^{ik}}$ - after multiplying nominator and denominator on $e^\epsilon$. It seems it is correct.

Comment: Oh, my mistake. I was wrong in the question. I will modify it

Comment: No worries. Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

**In addition to Svyatoslav's answer**

In order to prove that $$\delta_\varepsilon(k) =\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{\varepsilon}{\varepsilon^2+k^2}$$ is a nascent delta function we have to consider it's definition:

A sequence $(\delta_\alpha)_{\alpha\in\mathbb{N}}$ of integrable functions $\delta_\alpha\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is called a nacent delta function if

1. for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\alpha\in\mathbb{N}$, $(\delta_\alpha)_{\alpha\in\mathbb{N}}\ge0,$
2. for all $\alpha\in\mathbb{N}$, $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\delta_{\alpha}(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=1,$$
3. for all $\varepsilon$, $$\lim_{\alpha \to \infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n \setminus B_\varepsilon (0)} \delta_{\alpha}(x) \mathrm{d}x = 0.$$

It can easily be shown that the first condition is satisfied. I will prove condition 2. and I will leave 3. to to you. A hint: A sphere in $1$ dimension is a line. If you still have questions, ask in the comments.

We want to prove
$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{\varepsilon}{\varepsilon^2+k^2}\,\mathrm{d}k=1.$$
Substitute $x=k/\varepsilon$. We get
$$\frac{1}{\pi}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\varepsilon^2}{\varepsilon^2+k^2\varepsilon^2}\,\mathrm{d}k = \frac{1}{\pi}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x.$$
This is a well known integral, the $\arctan$. Applying the limits
$$\frac{1}{\pi}\left[\arctan x\right]_{-\infty}^\infty = \frac{\pi}{\pi} = 1.$$

If you prove the third condition right, we can conclude that
$$\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{\varepsilon}{\varepsilon^2+k^2} = \delta(k).$$

Comment: Good and detailed explanation. Thank you.

Comment: Great! Thank you.

Comment: And thank you for the edit suggestion. I like the new title.

Answer (score 2):

The [Dirichlet Kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_kernel) is a Fourier Series approximations to the Dirac delta. It relies on cancellation rather than decay away from $0$. The [Fejér Kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fej%C3%A9r_kernel) makes a better approximation to the Dirac delta since it is positive and decays to $0$ away from $0$.
$$
\sum_{k=-n}^ne^{ikx}=\underbrace{\frac{\sin\left(\frac{2n+1}2x\right)}{\sin\left(\frac12x\right)}}_{2\pi\times\text{Dirichlet Kernel}}
$$
If we multiply this by $e^{inx}$ we get
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{2n}e^{ikx}
&=\frac{\sin\left(\frac{2n+1}2x\right)}{\sin\left(\frac12x\right)}\,e^{inx}\\[3pt]
&=\frac12\left(\vphantom{\frac{\frac12}{\frac12}}\!\right.\underbrace{\frac{\sin\left(\frac{4n+1}2x\right)}{\sin\left(\frac12x\right)}}_{2\pi\times\text{Dirichlet Kernel}}+1\left.\vphantom{\frac{\frac12}{\frac12}}\!\right)+\frac i2\cot\left(\frac12x\right)\left(\vphantom{\frac{\frac12}{\frac12}}\!\right.1-\underbrace{\frac{\cos\left(\frac{4n+1}2x\right)}{\cos\left(\frac12x\right)}}_{\substack{2\pi\times\text{Dirichlet Kernel}\\\text{rotated by $\pi$,}\\\text{which is killed}\\\text{by $\cot\left(\frac12x\right)$}}}\left.\vphantom{\frac{\frac12}{\frac12}}\!\right)
\end{align}
$$
So the real part tends to $\frac12(2\pi\delta+1)$ the imaginary part tends to $\frac12\cot\left(\frac12x\right)$.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Very good. Much simpler! Thanks

Comment: Clever approach!